# Implement IDisposable in derived class

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

If I have interface (example from apress book) which implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) like this

```
public interface IArchitectRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Architect> GetArchitects();
    Architect GetAchitectDetails(int id);
    void Create(Achitect a);
    void Update(Achitect a);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Save();
}
```

how would I implement Dispose method in derived class?

In book the it's left as [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx).

Comment: First make sure you understand what the disposable pattern *is* and what it is good for. Once you know that you can answer the question yourself. (We can't answer it except for generic advice because we don't know what your repository does).

Comment: IArchitectRepository is not implementing IDisposable but inheriting it, so you should be able to implement the dispose method in your class which implementing IArchitectRepository interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason why you would implement the Dispose pattern any differently than normal.

See [Implementing a Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Comment: Well, as per the link you gave, the child class has to use override with the Dispose method, and the child class doesn't not provide an overloaded version of the Dispose method. I'd call those different than normal. And of course the child class doesn't implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most interfaces which imply obligations on the part of an implementing class, the only obligation of a class which implements `IDisposable` is to regard a call to `Dispose` as adequate notice that an instance is going to be abandoned.  The real obligations imparted by `IDisposable` fall upon instance owners: if a type implements `IDisposable`, each instance should have one owner who is obligated to ensure that its `Dispose` method will gets called before it's abandoned; the owner may do this either by calling `Dispose` itself, or passing ownership to a new owner who would then assume the obligation.

Note that the owner of an `IDisposable` instance doesn't care what `Dispose` does provided that the instance may be safely abandoned after it returns.  If some particular object can be safely abandoned before `Dispose` is called, there's no need for the `Dispose` method to do anything.  It should *not* throw a `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException`, since it should be no able to doing everything it needs to do (i.e. nothing).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at MSDN for the complete example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

The minimum would be:

```
public class ArchitectRepository : IArchitectRepository
{
    // implement all the IArchitectRepository methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // assuming your repository has a connection property
        if (this.Connection != null)
            this.Connection.Close();
        // do the same for all other disposable objects your repository has created.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Whiting the concrete implementation you can overwrite as follows

```
        public bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

        public bool IsLockedForDisposing { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose the Loaded Context
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Disposing of managed code
                    context.Dispose();
                    // GC.Collect(context);
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!IsLockedForDisposing)
            {
                IsDisposed = true;
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: don't ever call GC.Collect!  It actually hurts performance.

Answer (score -1):

I have some example code posted here (and included below): [How do you properly implement the IDisposable pattern?](https://dave-black.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html)

Microsoft has slightly more in-depth details here: [Implement a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

```
#region IDisposable base-class implementation
 
//TODO remember to make this class inherit from IDisposable -> MyDisposableClass : IDisposable
 
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is disposed.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///  <c>true</c> if this instance is disposed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </value>
/// <remarks>Default initialization for a bool is 'false'</remarks>
private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
 
/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Dispose according to .NET Framework Design Guidelines.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Do not make this method virtual.
/// A derived class should not be able to override this method.
/// </remarks>
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
 
    // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
    // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
    // take this object off the finalization queue 
    // and prevent finalization code for this object
    // from executing a second time.
 
    // Always use SuppressFinalize() in case a subclass
    // of this type implements a finalizer.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
 
/// <summary>
/// Overloaded Implementation of Dispose.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="isDisposing"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; 
/// <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// <list type="bulleted">Dispose(bool isDisposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
/// <item>If <paramref name="isDisposing"/> equals true, the method has been called directly
/// or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
/// can be disposed.</item>
/// <item>If <paramref name="isDisposing"/> equals <c>false</c>, the method has been called 
/// by the runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference
/// other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.</item></list>
/// </remarks>
protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
{
    // TODO If you need thread safety, use a lock around these 
    // operations, as well as in your methods that use the resource.
    try
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            // Explicitly set root references to null to expressly tell the GarbageCollector
            // that the resources have been disposed of and its ok to release the memory 
            // allocated for them.
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                // Release all managed resources here
                // Need to unregister/detach yourself from the events. Always make sure
                // the object is not null first before trying to unregister/detach them!
                // Failure to unregister can be a BIG source of memory leaks
                if (someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler != null)
                {                 
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler.SomeEvent -= someDelegate;
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler.Dispose();
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler = null;
                }
                // If this is a WinForm/UI control, uncomment this code
                //if (components != null)
                //{
                //    components.Dispose();
                //}
            }
            // Release all unmanaged resources here  
            // (example)             if (someComObject != null && Marshal.IsComObject(someComObject))
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(someComObject);
                someComObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.IsDisposed = true;
    }
}

//TODO Uncomment this code if this class will contain members which are UNmanaged
///// <summary>Finalizer for MyDisposableClass</summary>
///// <remarks>This finalizer will run only if the Dispose method does not get called.
///// It gives your base class the opportunity to finalize.
///// DO NOT provide finalizers in types derived from this class.
///// All code executed within a Finalizer MUST be thread-safe!</remarks>
//  ~MyDisposableClass()
//  {
//     Dispose( false );
//  }
#endregion IDisposable base-class implementation
 
Here is the code for properly implementing the IDisposable pattern in a derived class:

#region IDisposable derived-class implementation

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is disposed.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///  <c>true</c> if this instance is disposed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </value>
/// <remarks>Default initialization for a bool is 'false'</remarks>
private bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Overloaded Implementation of Dispose.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="isDisposing"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; 
/// <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// <list type="bulleted">Dispose(bool isDisposing) executes in two distinct scenarios.
/// <item>If <paramref name="isDisposing"/> equals true, the method has been called directly
/// or indirectly by a user's code. Managed and unmanaged resources
/// can be disposed.</item>
/// <item>If <paramref name="isDisposing"/> equals <c>false</c>, the method has been called

/// by the runtime from inside the finalizer and you should not reference
/// other objects. Only unmanaged resources can be disposed.</item></list>
/// </remarks>
protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
{
    // TODO If you need thread safety, use a lock around these 
    // operations, as well as in your methods that use the resource.
    try
    {
        if (!this.IsDisposed)
        {
            // Explicitly set root references to null to expressly tell the GarbageCollector
            // that the resources have been disposed of and its ok to release the memory 
            // allocated for them.
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                // Release all managed resources here

                // Need to unregister/detach yourself from the events. Always make sure
                // the object is not null first before trying to unregister/detach them!
                // Failure to unregister can be a BIG source of memory leaks
                if (someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler != null)
                {                 
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler.SomeEvent -= someDelegate;
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler.Dispose();
                    someDisposableObjectWithAnEventHandler = null;
                }
                // If this is a WinForm/UI contrlol, uncomment this code
                //if (components != null)
                //{
                //    components.Dispose();
                //}
            }

            // Release all unmanaged resources here
 
 
            // (example)
            if (someComObject != null && Marshal.IsComObject(someComObject))
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(someComObject);
                someComObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.IsDisposed = true;

        // explicitly call the base class Dispose implementation
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
#endregion IDisposable derived-class implementation
```